# Does selecting global state in generator make the function to be impure?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

When i used to select the current state in a saga generator, does this make the function to be impure function, and by this it will affect the way in uni testing,

```
const currentState = state => state;

function* doLogin(){
   const state = yield select(currentState);
   //The rest of the code...
}
```

in the above example, i'm accessing a global object. And when i need to write unit test for this method, i need to simulate the same behavior, which is accessing a global object, and by this way it's considered to be impure function, is this correct assumption?

Comment: Have you read the definition of a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) and that by that definition your function is not pure? If so, what is the real question?

Comment: Well, that's the issue :D, the definition isn't clear to me, it says mutate non-local var, but here i'm reference global var .

Comment: I was maybe to quick to say it is not pure. It depends on whether you have code that mutates the `currentState` object, and whether your function (what is `select`) would depend on such mutation.

Comment: If that global state is constant, it should be considered pure I imagine. It isn't mutating anything, and it is referentially transparent.

Comment: sagas are meant to be impure, and are designed to be easily testable regardless of that